# Installing QGIS on Mac OS X 10.13.2 with Python 3.4

Tags: pyqgis, installation

My first time installing QGIS.  ReadMe says QGIS uses Python 2.7. So, before I start Do I need to remove Python 3.4 or can I install 2.7 as well?

Comment: Mac os X, comes with Python 2.7 pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove it, QGIS installs its own python in the /bin/ folder (it also installs its own GDAL and its own postgres client).

Comment: Qgis does not install Python, it uses the Python version pre-installed